# Can't checkout source from Google Code

Tags: tortoise-svn, source-code, google-code

I'm trying to check out the project source for [MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/checkout)

Here's what it says on the site:

Non-members may check out a read-only working copy anonymously over HTTP.
svn checkout http://morelinq.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ morelinq-read-only

I'm using TortoiseSVN UI (not command line tool), and all i get is

> Error: URL
>   'http://morelinq.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/morelinq-read-only'
>   doesn't exist

any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
http://morelinq.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
```

the end bit is probably for the CLI users.

Comment: correct, the end part (with space between trunk/ and morelink-read-only) is just export folder for CLI